# Is it possible to extract audiofiles directly from the web?

Tags: browser, web, audio-recording

So this is what I want to do. I want to find two audio files for "fifteen" and "fifty" spoken by native speakers. [Cambridge Online Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english-chinese-simplified/fifteen) provide excellent quality audio files suited exactly for what I want, but I don't know how to extract that from its website.

I am aware that I could possibly use cloudflower to record it. But it will leave an ackward long pause between when I click "record" on whatever software I use to record audio and when I click the sound button on Cambridge dictionary online. The result will be a long ackward silence and I will have to put in some time and effort to clip the audio file shorter. That would be too much work.  So I wonder if there is an easier way.

I guess the answer is probably no, unless I am some kind of super hacker that can hack into their webserver or something. Just want to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path to the `.mp3`/`.ogg` files is in the source of the page (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>). But first you should ask Cambridge for permission.

Answer (score 1):

## If you have Firefox installed, there is a simple way to use the GUI:

1. Open your link in Firefox (Developer or not, both works)
2. Use <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> or Go to “Menu Tools -> Page Info”
3. Select/click on “Media,” then use “List by type,” and <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Click</kbd>  to select all desired items.
4. Click save as and browse to the desired drive and folder, click select.

[image]

---

[image]